# Submitting forms inside a custom plugin causing page redirect

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I have two issues with my plugin. The first being when I submit the form below it redirects me out of my plugin. This is the original link followed by the redirect link;

```
https://mywebsite.uk/wp-admin/admin.php?page=plugin-name&paged=1
https://mywebsite.uk/wp-admin/admin.php?search=hello
```

All I want to do is add the search query to the current link / queries. Why am I being redirected?

My second issue is that I want to be able to add the search meta query to my $args
if it has been set. I know how to check if it is set but I have no idea how I could then add it to the $args. For now I have simply put the query inside an if statement see code below.

```
<?php
    $current_page = ( $_GET['paged'] ) ? $_GET['paged'] : 1;
    $users_per_page = 100;

    $args = array(
        'number' => $users_per_page,
        'paged' => $current_page,
    );

    $users = new WP_User_Query( $args );

    if( $_GET['search'] ){
        'meta_query'    => array(
            'relation'  => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'   => 'first_name',
                'value' => $_GET['search'],
                'compare'   => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    }
?>

<form action="" method="GET">
    <label>
        Search: 
        <input type="text" name="search">
    </label>
</form>
```

**Update**

If I change GET to POST on my form I no longer get a redirect. This doesn't solve my issue as I need to use GET but maybe it will help figure this out

Answer (score 3):

For the redirect you can look at the initializer you call at `new WP_User_Query( $args );`. Maybe this does the redirect?

To add the search query to the args, you can move your if statement up and check that first.

```php
<?php
    $current_page = ( $_GET['paged'] ) ? $_GET['paged'] : 1;
    $users_per_page = 100;

    $args = array(
        'number' => $users_per_page,
        'paged' => $current_page,
    );

    if( $_GET['search'] ){
        $args['meta_query'] = array(
            'relation'  => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'   => 'first_name',
                'value' => $_GET['search'],
                'compare'   => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    };

    $users = new WP_User_Query( $args );
?>

<form action="" method="GET">
    <label>
        Search: 
        <input type="text" name="search">
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks the query you created works perfectly. As for the redirect I have no idea how new WP_User_Query( $args ); could be causing this. Do you have any more info on this or is this just a guess?

Comment: That was just a guess, since that is the only unknown in the code you've posted. Looking into the documentation it seems like it doesn't do a redirect. I am not a WP expert, so I don't think I can help you with that unfortunately. I am happy that the query works for you.

Comment: I believe I figured it out. I am using a custom plugin so the page is something like https://website.uk/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my_plugin when you use get it strips out any querys as it can't append onto the end of a query. So it would redirect me to admin.php